# Broadcom Wireless for Compaq 615 on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a problem where after recent updates my Wifi stopped working. I can detect my wireless network but when attempting to join it the wifi icon in the task bar just 'rolls' the wifi signal indicator up and down and never actually connects. It would often ask for the password a few times. I've tried changing the Wifi password, restarting the machine, disabling/enabling the wifi adapter, but nothing seems to be working. I can see the network but just can't connect.

Please help. How can I fix this.

I am using: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

The 14e4 was Orange/red in the report, not sure if that means something?

Anyone know I can can get my laptop to actually connect to the Wifi again?

Comment: The answer depends on your Ubuntu version. Please edit your question to add the result of: lsb_release -d

Comment: After doing what Premkumar suggested and the issue still not being resolved; I again went to System Settings > Additional Drivers. There is shows 'Broadcom STA Wireless Driver (grayed out) When I click "activate" it says "Failed to install driver"

Comment: Yes, it is the wrong driver for your device. However, we need to know your Ubuntu version as I asked above in order to propose a solution.

Comment: I have updated the questions title. The version is: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Now, with a temporary wired ethernet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us have your report.

Comment: After restarting I can no longer see 'Wireless Network' in the Network settings or when clicking on the networking icon in the task bar. The physical/hardware wifi button on the compaq is lit up as 'on' but pressing the button to try disable/enable again does nothing, it just stays on even though the wireless networking device isn't listed in network settings.

Comment: I've removed all the drivers again, reset my router to factory settings again, followed your instructions again AND what was previously suggested. Then restarted and now it's working. No idea which driver is being used now and no idea if the wifi router factory reset also helped but I'm glad that it's working now. How to I check which driver is being used so that I can report back here?

Comment: Please check: lsmod. It should be b43.

Comment: Not sure which item on the list is the wireless. I assume this:
cfg80211 181041 1 wl - I don't see b43 anywhere.

Comment: If _wl_ is loaded, then you didn't purge bcmwl-kernel-source or you reinstalled it!! Please retrace your steps; try my steps again and tell us the result.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment; my wifi is working now. I'd rather not break it tying to replace the driver again.